# How to filter query in Django template? Need to filter posts based on category

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-orm

Here is view:

```
def all(request):
products = Product.objects.all()
context = {'products': products}
template = 'products/all.html'  
return render(request, template, context)
```

And model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
```

Now, in template, I want to get posts in various areas based on category. I tried with:

```
{% for product in products %}
{% if product.category == "womens-clothin" %}
```

but it didn't work. Also, tried on views:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(category='womens-clothin')
```

but none worked. How to figure this out?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `'womens-clothing'`?

Answer (score 3):

You cant do like this,

```
products = Product.objects.filter(category='womens-clothin')
```

because category is type of `ManyToManyField` not `string`.

First take Category object. Something like ,

```
some_category = Category.objects.get(category_name="SOMETHING")
```

and then perform,

```
products = Product.objects.all().filter(category=some_category)
```

Comment: So, what is my option?

Comment: Any way, thanks. got answer. Need to use category id.... `products = Product.objects.filter(category__id=1)`